# Class instance variables and instance variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop

```
class Var
  @instance_variable = "instance variable"
  @@class_instance_variable = "class instance variable"

  def self.class_method
    puts @instance_variable
    puts @@class_instance_variable
  end

  def instance_method
    puts @instance_variable
    puts @@class_instance_variable
  end

end
```

The class method has access to both class instance and instance variables. But the instance method has just access to class instance variable. `@instance_variable` is nil inside instance method. What is the logical explanation behind this?

```
Var.class_method #=> "instance variable" "class instance variable"
Var.new.instance_method #=> "class instance variable" nil
```

And is it correct that the instance variables dont get inherited by child classes? Why is that?

Comment: _Sidenote_: `nil` in shown result of `Var.new.instance_method` execution is confusing, since it a) should appear before "class instance variable" and b) won’t appear at all in `puts`.

Comment: It goes as follows. (You must replace my (@) with @, as ampersands begin SO usernames and SO only permits one per comment.) `class A; (@)(@)class_variable = 1; (@)class_instance_variable = 2; def my_method; (@)instance_variable = 3; end; end`

Comment: @FrederickCheung I disagree that this is a duplicate. OP in fact asks “`@instance_variable` is nil inside instance method. What is the logical explanation behind this?” It was induced by the fact OP misunderstands the notion of instance variable scoping at all.

Comment: Your question is wrong.. @@ is a class variable. not what you labelled it, you got that wrong every time you wrote @@var.  The variable you put at the top with @ is a class instance variable, so you didn't label that one well. And the other @var instance variables you labelled ok.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `class Var` (not `Class Var`!), as well as inside the class method, `self` is `Var`, `self.class` is `Class`. Inside `def instance_method`, `self.class` is `Var`. The class variable is designed to be there; but the instance variable is defined on `Var` as an instance of `Class` class. If you have `v = Var.new`, then `@instance_variable` is looking at the `@instance_variable` on `v`, which is not there.

No, variables are never inherited; only methods are. Variables represent object state, and are specific to each object; inheritance is a relationship between two classes.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you have not defined instance variable on `Var`’s instance at all.

```
▶ Var.class_variables
#⇒ [:@@class_instance_variable]
▶ Var.instance_variables
#⇒ [ :@instance_variable ]
▶ Var.new.instance_variables
#⇒ []
```

What you have defined, are: class variable on `Var` and **class instance variable on `Var`, an instance of `Class` class**. This is because you have it declared in *class scope*.

To define an instance variable on `Var`’s instance, one should call `@iv` *from the respective scope*, namely—from inside one of the instance methods of `Var`:

```
▶ class Var
▷   def iv
▷     @iv ||= 42
▷   end
▷​ end
▶ Var.new.instance_variables
#⇒ []
# the above is because instance variables are lazily instantiated
▶ v = Var.new
▶ v.iv
#⇒ 42
▶ v.instance_variables
#⇒ [ :@iv ]
```

Answer (score 0):

A class variable is shared among a class, its instances, subclasses, and their instances.

An instance variable takes scope only within a single instance. When undefined, it returns `nil` as a language design.